# Is there a Ruby equivalent for the typeof reserved word in C#?

Tags: c#, ruby

I have a C# method that I need to call from a piece of Ruby that requires a System.Type argument.  Is there a Ruby equivalent to typeof in C#?  The call will look something like this in C# ...

var CustomClasInstance = Container.GetInstance(typeof(ICustomClass))

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In addition to checking Object#class (the instance method class on the Object aka Base class), you could

```
s.is_a? Thing
```

this will check to see if s has Thing anywhere in its ancestry.

Answer (score 64):

Either `Object.class` or `Object.type` should do what you need.

Also, the two methods `Object.is_a?` and `Object.instance_of?` can be used.  However, they are not 100% identical.  The statement `obj.instance_of?(myClass)` will return true only if object `obj` was created as an object of type `myClass`.  Using `obj.is_a?(myClass)` will return true if the object `obj` is of class `myClass`, is of a class that has inherited from `myClass`, or has the module `myClass` included in it.

For example:

```
x = 1
x.class                   => Fixnum
x.instance_of? Integer    => false
x.instance_of? Numeric    => false
x.instance_of? Fixnum     => true
x.is_a? Integer           => true
x.is_a? Numeric           => true
x.is_a? Fixnum            => true
```

Since your C# method requires a very specific data type, I would recommend using `Object.instance_of?`.

Answer (score 7):

For a reference on how to identify variable types in Ruby, see 
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Ruby_Variables#Identifying_a_Ruby_Variable_Type

If you have variable named `s`, you can retrieve the type of it by invoking

> ```
> s.class
> ```

Comment: It looks like s.Class is more like CustomClassInstance.GetType() and not really like typeof(CustomClass) ... am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

```
ICustomClass.to_clr_type
```